# How to keep an element hidden, let it occupy its space and make it appear at that position?

Tags: jquery, html, css, visibility

I was learning jQuery from a website and stumbled upon an example demonstrating fadeIn() & fadeOut() . How can i make the "visibility:hidden" elements appear or "display:none" elements to take up their original space while they are hidden?

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
  $("#div1").fadeIn();
  $("#div2").fadeIn("slow");
  $("#div3").fadeOut(3000); 
 });
 });
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Demonstrate fadeIn() with different parameters.</p>
  <button>Click to fade in boxes</button>
  <br><br>
  <div id="div1" style="width:80px;height:80px;display:none;background-color:red;"></div>
  <br>
  <div id="div2" style="width:80px;height:80px;display:none;background-color:green;"></div>
  <br>
  <div id="div3" style="width:80px;height:80px;background-color:blue;"></div>`
```

Comment: You're looking for Visibility.

Comment: Actually i tried visibility, but but unlike display:none, it doesn't really appear when i click the button!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add a `parent <div>` to all the divs to hold the position…

Check this fiddle… Don't know if it is what you want…

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uRTe2/)

Comment: Thanks a lot Bhaskar, this is exactly what i was trying to get!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `visibility : visible|hidden`

For fade effect you can change opacity -

```
.animate({opacity:1}); // 0 to make it invisible and 1 to make it visible.
```

Animate `--->` http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 1):

Use `visibility: hidden` to begin, and when you're ready to display them, set the css to `visibility: visible`

Answer (score 1):

You want `visibility:hidden;` to hide the element but still have it in place.

http://jsfiddle.net/EbbUh/